# Encoding of different language characters

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I want to read the name "Anna Häuser" and save into a file but the problem is this is not encoding as it is and converting like to "Anna H�user", how can I do this?

I am using this code for encoding:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<getData> getData = new List<getData>();
getData.Add(new getData { imagename = "Picture1", date = "03.02.2014", customernumber = 9, name = "Anna Häuser" });
var jobject = getData;
string str = serializer.Serialize(jobject);

  string utf8String = str ;
        string propEncodeString = string.Empty;

        byte[] utf8_Bytes = new byte[utf8String.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < utf8String.Length; ++i)
        {
            utf8_Bytes[i] = (byte)utf8String[i];
        }

        propEncodeString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8_Bytes, 0, utf8_Bytes.Length);

string outputpath = @"C:\ResizeImages\ResizeImages\jsondataoutput.txt";

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputpath, propEncodeString, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `File.WriteAllText(outputpath, str, Encoding.UTF8)` (or Unicode), instead of all that bad custom encoding stuff.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your actual input is, but your attempt at encoding it is a really bad idea. What happens if you just use `File.WriteAllText(outputpath, str)`? What encoding do you *want* the result in?

Comment: I agree with previous commenters. Why convert the string to utf8 first and then to unicode? Why not write directly as unicode in the writer?

Comment: yeah thanks man, its working without using all this stuff.

Comment: File.WriteAllText(outputpath, str, Encoding.UTF8), thanks Dirk